# Unwanted characters in Acrobat PDF conversion of auto-detected Word fillable fields. Deleting fillable field characters using iTextSharp5

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrobat

Acrobat DC, Office 365, iTextSharp5, Win10 Pro 64-bit

I have a Word document containing several pages of text and one empty TextBox in between two of the lines.  I am attempting to use the Acrobat "Prepare Form" feature to convert that document to PDF with the TextBox as a fillable field, and Acrobat has no problem auto detecting the TextBox and making it fillable.  The problem, however, is that the converted TextBox contains text from either the line of text above it or below it.

I've read that this is caused by placing the TextBox too close to those lines in the Word document and sure enough, by leaving three or four empty lines of space above and below the text box the issue goes away.  However, that's an unacceptable amount of wasted space. I tried putting continuous section breaks above and below the TextBox in Word as well as typing spaces in the TextBox but that doesn't help.  I also tried it with a 1x1 table instead of a TextBox but the same problem occurred.

I then tried deleting the unwanted text from the PDF TextBox field and saving it that way, which appeared to be a reasonable solution.  However, when I used an iTextSharp5 program to detect the PDF's fillable fields it could no longer detect the empty field.  I wouldn't mind leaving the original unwanted text in the PDF TextBox field if there were some way to remove it with iTextSharp, but it doesn't seem to have that ability.

Because I have many Word documents to convert to fillable PDF's and might need to update them occasionally, it simply isn't practical for me to manually add the fillable fields to the converted PDFs each time an update is needed.  Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF with such a problematic form field?

Comment: There must have been something wrong in my Word file or my iTextSharp code.  I retested it with a fresh Word file and cleaned up my iTextSharp code and, although the extraneous characters were still in the converted PDF fields as before (and as expected), writing to those fields with my iTextSharp program cleared out that garbage and left only what iTextSharp had just written.  It's somewhat magic but at least it's working now.